# Can my brother and I play on the same PS4 console with two different PS+ accounts?

Tags: ps4, star-wars-battlefront-2015

So my brother has a PlayStation Plus account and so do I, but when trying to play multiplayer online for the new Battlefront game, they wouldn't allow me to play. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Is there a specific error message that's displayed?  We'll be of more help if you provide some more details.

Comment: Updating your tag. Bit confusing, as this is the third game, but its title is simply "battlefront"

Answer (score 1):

No.

Split screen play is limited to non-online mission modes.